# TypeScript expect(received).toThrow() Matcher error

Tags: javascript, jestjs

So here is the function I want to test

```
export const dateToDays = async (date: string): Promise<number | Error> => {
  try {
    if (date === "") throw new Error("foo");
    const now: any = new Date(date);
    const start: any = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
    const diff =
      now -
      start +
      (start.getTimezoneOffset() - now.getTimezoneOffset()) * 60 * 1000;
    const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    const day = Math.floor(diff / oneDay);
    return Number(day);
  } catch (err) {
    return err;
  }
};
```

And here is my test

```
describe("exception test", () => {
  it("should throw an error", () => {
    expect(dateToDays("")).toThrow('foo');
  });
});
```

And the error I get is

```
Error: expect(received).toThrow()
Matcher error: received value must be a function
Received has type:  object
Received has value: {}Jest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toThrow` is only for synchronous code execution, but your `dateToDays` is asynchronous. Furthermore, you should only pass a *function* to something called with `toThrow`, but you're passing it a Promise.

From [the docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async), use `.rejects` to check if a Promise rejects:

```
expect(dateToDays("")).rejects.toEqual(new Error('foo'));
```

Since it sounds like you want the function to return a Promise that rejects, you also shouldn't wrap it in a `try`/`catch` - let the error percolate up to the caller:

```
export const dateToDays = async (date: string): Promise<number> => {
    if (date === "") throw new Error("foo");
    const now: any = new Date(date);
    const start: any = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
    const diff =
      now -
      start +
      (start.getTimezoneOffset() - now.getTimezoneOffset()) * 60 * 1000;
    const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    const day = Math.floor(diff / oneDay);
    return Number(day);
};
```

Comment: I now get `Received promise resolved instead of rejected
Resolved to value: [Error: foo]Jest`

Comment: Your `try`/`catch` is making it return a resolved Promise instead of rejecting. Since it sounds like you want the test to see that it rejects, remove the `try`/`catch`.